# Does a Joker have the value of the number it represents when played as part of the initial minimum 30 point row?

Tags: rummikub, joker

I played Rummikub yesterday and you know: To start a game, one has to lay down a minimum of 30 Points with new rows created.

However, yesterday, my mom laid out following:

`[11] [11] [JO]`

In my Computer Rummikub, this isn't allowed, but my mom said we will keep this rule. I said that I will ask on a very good forum, if this is allowed.

So when attaching the Joker to a row, will it get assigned the value of the number it represents? Or will it only stand for this number, as I think, with having a value attribute of zero?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is clearly stated in [the rules](http://www.boardgamecapital.com/game_rules/rummikub.pdf) (section "The Joker:"):

> A joker used in the opening set scores the value of the tiles it represents.

So your mom was right and the Computer uses its own rules.